# problems with angular directive

Tags: angularjs

i'm trying to use custom directive and get error 
Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngChange', can't be found!

It's strange, because i'm using ng-model directive:

```
<input type="password" same-as ng-model="confirmPassword" />

app.ns('rm.ng.controllers', function ($root, $ns) {
    this.MyCTR= function (scope, myService) {
        scope.confirmPassword = '';
    };
});


app.ns('rm.ng.directives', function ($root, $ns) {
    this.sameAs = function ($parse, $compile, myService) {
        this.restrict = "A";
        this.link = function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log("asdfasdfasdf");
        };
    };
});
```

Comment: Is there any other input on page that fires NgChnage Event?

Comment: yes, I didn't even think about it. it was checkbox without model, but with ng-change event. thanks